# How to record information from an HTML table in Razor Pages?

Tags: jquery, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I created a page with Razor pages, where I use a procedure in the OnGetAsync method to bring up a salary calculation. I would like to save the same information that was generated in an HTML table in another table in the SQL database using the procedure in the OnPostAsync method. I've looked at many examples on the web, but I can't make it work! Thank you for your help in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


namespace RPMCarpentryManager.Models;
   
[Keyless]   
public class ModelGeneratePayments
{

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Employee ID")]
    public int EmployerID {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Employee Full Name")]
    public string ? EmployeeFullName {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Worked Hours")]
    public string ? WorkedHours {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Wage per Hour")]
    public decimal SalaryHour {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Gross Salary")]
    public decimal SalaryWorked {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Bonus for Driving")]
    public decimal DriverBonus {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Extra Bonus")]
    public decimal ExtraBonus {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Advance")]
    public decimal Advance {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("% Tax Discount")]
    public decimal TaxDiscount {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Tax Discount")]
    public decimal ValueTaxDiscount {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("NET Salary")]
    public decimal SalaryToBePaid {get; set;}
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace RPMCarpentryManager.Models;
   
   
public class ModelPeriodPayment
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("#")]
    public int PaymentID {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Payment Date")]
    public DateTime PaymentDate {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Payment Date")]
    public string ? DateSearched {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Employer ID ")]
    public int EmployerID {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Worked Hours")]
    public string ? WorkedHours {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Wage per Hour")]
    public decimal SalaryHour {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Gross Salary")]
    public decimal SalaryWorked {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Bonus for Driving")]
    public decimal DriverBonus {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Extra Bonus")]
    public decimal ExtraBonus {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Advance")]
    public decimal Advance {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("% Tax Discount")]
    public decimal TaxDiscount {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Tax Discount")]
    public decimal ValueTaxDiscount {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("NET Salary")]
    public decimal SalaryToBePaid {get; set;}
}
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RPMCarpentryManager.Data;
using RPMCarpentryManager.Models;

namespace RPMCarpentryManager.Pages.Payments
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly RPMContext _context;

        public CreateModel(RPMContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<ModelGeneratePayments> ModelGeneratePayments { get;set; } = default!;

        [BindProperty]
        public IList<ModelPeriodPayment> ModelPeriodPaymentOnPost { get; set; } = default!;

        // --------------------------Start Paramenters--------------------------

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string? DateFrom { get; set; } = default!;

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string? DateTo { get; set; } = default!;
        // --------------------------End Paramenters--------------------------

        public void OnGetAsync()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DateFrom) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(DateTo))
            {
                var parameter = new List<SqlParameter>
                {
                    new("@DateFrom", DateFrom),
                    new("@DateTo", DateTo)
                };
                ModelGeneratePayments =  _context.ModelGeneratePayments.FromSqlRaw("[STP_ListPayment] @DateFrom, @DateTo", parameter.ToArray()).ToList();
            }
        }

        

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {

            foreach(var item in ModelPeriodPaymentOnPost)
            {
                var parameter = new List<SqlParameter>
                {
                    new("@PaymentDate", DateTime.Now),
                    new("@DateSearched", string.Concat(DateFrom," up to ",DateTo)),
                    new("@EmployerID", item.EmployerID),
                    new("@WorkedHours", item.WorkedHours),
                    new("@SalaryHour", item.SalaryHour),
                    new("@SalaryWorked", item.SalaryWorked),
                    new("@DriverBonus", item.DriverBonus),
                    new("@ExtraBonus", item.ExtraBonus),
                    new("@Advance", item.Advance),
                    new("@TaxDiscount", item.TaxDiscount),
                    new("@ValueTaxDiscount", item.ValueTaxDiscount),
                    new("@SalaryToBePaid", item.SalaryToBePaid)
                };
                await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("STP_CreatePayments @PaymentDate, @DateSearched, @EmployerID, @WorkedHours, @SalaryHour, @SalaryWorked, @DriverBonus, @ExtraBonus, @Advance, @TaxDiscount, @ValueTaxDiscount, @SalaryToBePaid", parameter.ToArray());
            }
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}
```

```
@page
@model RPMCarpentryManager.Pages.Payments.CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<div class="content">
    <div class="mb-9">
        <div class="row g-3 mb-4">
            <div class="col-auto">
                <h4>Generate Payment</h4>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="mb-4">
            <div class="d-flex flex-wrap gap-3">
                <div class="search-box">
                    <form class="position-relative">
                        <div class="scrollbar overflow-hidden-y">
                            <div class="btn-group position-static">
                                <div class="btn-group position-static text-nowrap">
                                </div>
                                <div class="btn-group position-static text-nowrap">
                                    <input type='text' id="datepickerFrom" class="form-control" asp-for="DateFrom"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="btn-group position-static text-nowrap">
                                    <input type='text' id="datepickerTo" class="form-control" asp-for="DateTo"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="btn-group position-static text-nowrap">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Generate" class="btn btn-success" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="ms-xxl-auto">
                    <form asp-page-handler="Create" method="post">
                        <input id="buttonPost" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </form>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
            <table id="tblPayment" class="table table-bordered border-dark" style="background-color: white;">
                <thead class="table-dark">
                    <tr class="titlerow">
                        <th class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].EmployerID)
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].EmployeeFullName)
                        </th>   
                        <th class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].WorkedHours)
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].SalaryHour)
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].SalaryWorked)
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].DriverBonus)
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].ExtraBonus)
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].Advance)
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].TaxDiscount)
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].ValueTaxDiscount)
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].SalaryToBePaid)
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @if(Model.ModelGeneratePayments != null)
                    {
                    @foreach (var item in Model.ModelGeneratePayments) 
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployerID)
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeFullName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkedHours)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SalaryHour)
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SalaryWorked)
                            </td>
                            <td class="rowDataSd" style="text-align:center">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DriverBonus)
                            </td>
                            <td class="rowDataSd" style="text-align:center">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExtraBonus)
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;color:red">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Advance)
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaxDiscount)
                            </td>
                            <td class="rowDataSd" style="text-align:center">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ValueTaxDiscount)
                            </td>
                            <td class="rowDataSd" style="text-align:center">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SalaryToBePaid)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }}
                </tbody>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.14/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.14/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
    <script>
        $('#datepickerFrom').datepicker({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap'
        });
        $('#datepickerTo').datepicker({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap'
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? When you debug how far does it get? What does and does not work? We can't run it, so we can't see where it's failing

Answer (score 0):

According to your codes, I guess you want to post the List of ModelPeriodPayment to the Onpostasync method.

But the ModelPeriodPaymentOnPost is same as the ModelGeneratePayments with just three properties.

Normally, for kind of condition, we will just one model instead of two inside the razor pages.

So inside the OnPost() method, you should directly use the ModelGeneratePayments instead of the ModelPeriodPaymentOnPost, since they are almost same and the property you have used is also inside the ModelGeneratePayments.

There is no need to use ModelPeriodPaymentOnPost inside this page.

Then inside the razor page ,you should put the form include the table and add the  input type="hidden"  to let the client know which data should post to the backend.

More details, you could refer to below details codes.

Razor pages:

```
@page
@model WebApplicationRazorIdentity.Pages.CreateModel
@{
}


<form asp-page-handler="Create" method="post">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="mb-9">
            <div class="row g-3 mb-4">
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <h4>Generate Payment</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="mb-4">
                <div class="d-flex flex-wrap gap-3">
                    <div class="search-box">
                        <form class="position-relative">
                            <div class="scrollbar overflow-hidden-y">
                                <div class="btn-group position-static">
                                    <div class="btn-group position-static text-nowrap">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-group position-static text-nowrap">
                                        <input type='text' id="datepickerFrom" class="form-control" asp-for="DateFrom" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-group position-static text-nowrap">
                                        <input type='text' id="datepickerTo" class="form-control" asp-for="DateTo" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-group position-static text-nowrap">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Generate" class="btn btn-success" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ms-xxl-auto">
                  
                            <input id="buttonPost" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
                <table id="tblPayment" class="table table-bordered border-dark" style="background-color: white;">
                    <thead class="table-dark">
                        <tr class="titlerow">
                            <th class="text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].EmployerID)
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].EmployeeFullName)
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].WorkedHours)
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].SalaryHour)
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].SalaryWorked)
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].DriverBonus)
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].ExtraBonus)
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].Advance)
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].TaxDiscount)
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].ValueTaxDiscount)
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelGeneratePayments[0].SalaryToBePaid)
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @if (Model.ModelGeneratePayments != null)
                        {
 
                            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ModelGeneratePayments.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].EmployerID)
                                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].EmployerID" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">
                              
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].EmployeeFullName)
                                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].EmployeeFullName" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                 
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].WorkedHours)
                                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].WorkedHours" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                   
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].SalaryHour)
                                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].SalaryHour" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">
                               
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].SalaryWorked)
                                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].SalaryWorked" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="rowDataSd" style="text-align:center">
                                     
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].DriverBonus)
                                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].DriverBonus" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="rowDataSd" style="text-align:center">
                                      
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].ExtraBonus)
                                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].ExtraBonus" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center;color:red">
                                   
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].Advance)
                                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].Advance" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">
                                   

                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].TaxDiscount)
                                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].TaxDiscount" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="rowDataSd" style="text-align:center">
                             

                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].ValueTaxDiscount)
                                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].ValueTaxDiscount" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="rowDataSd" style="text-align:center">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].SalaryToBePaid)
                                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ModelGeneratePayments[i].SalaryToBePaid" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }

                        }

                       
                    </tbody>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</form>


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.14/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.14/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
    <script>
        $('#datepickerFrom').datepicker({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap'
        });
        $('#datepickerTo').datepicker({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap'
        });
    </script>
}
```

Backend:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;

namespace WebApplicationRazorIdentity.Pages
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public IList<ModelGeneratePayments> ModelGeneratePayments { get; set; } = default!;

    
        public IList<ModelPeriodPayment> ModelPeriodPaymentOnPost { get; set; } = default!;
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string? DateFrom { get; set; } = default!;

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string? DateTo { get; set; } = default!;
        public void OnGet()
        {
            //I directly new the data instead of querying them from database
            ModelGeneratePayments = new List<ModelGeneratePayments> { new ModelGeneratePayments { Advance=11, DriverBonus=22,  EmployeeFullName="aaa", EmployerID =1, ExtraBonus=22, SalaryHour=2,  SalaryToBePaid=1, SalaryWorked=1, TaxDiscount=2, ValueTaxDiscount=3, WorkedHours="1" },
                              new ModelGeneratePayments { Advance=11, DriverBonus=22, EmployeeFullName="aaa", EmployerID =1, ExtraBonus=22, SalaryHour=2,  SalaryToBePaid=1, SalaryWorked=1, TaxDiscount=2, ValueTaxDiscount=3, WorkedHours="1" } };


 

        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {

            foreach (var item in ModelGeneratePayments)
            {
                var parameter = new List<SqlParameter>
                {
                    new("@PaymentDate", DateTime.Now),
                    new("@DateSearched", string.Concat(DateFrom," up to ",DateTo)),
                    new("@EmployerID", item.EmployerID),
                    new("@WorkedHours", item.WorkedHours),
                    new("@SalaryHour", item.SalaryHour),
                    new("@SalaryWorked", item.SalaryWorked),
                    new("@DriverBonus", item.DriverBonus),
                    new("@ExtraBonus", item.ExtraBonus),
                    new("@Advance", item.Advance),
                    new("@TaxDiscount", item.TaxDiscount),
                    new("@ValueTaxDiscount", item.ValueTaxDiscount),
                    new("@SalaryToBePaid", item.SalaryToBePaid)
                };
                //await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("STP_CreatePayments @PaymentDate, @DateSearched, @EmployerID, @WorkedHours, @SalaryHour, @SalaryWorked, @DriverBonus, @ExtraBonus, @Advance, @TaxDiscount, @ValueTaxDiscount, @SalaryToBePaid", parameter.ToArray());
            }
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]